# How to get cookie from a response and set it on next request in Ruby on Rails while hitting 3rd party URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, cookies, session-cookies

I was working on Postman.

But now I want to hit an URL, get the response along with cookies and set it, to send it to consecutive URLs.

How to do this in Ruby Rails?

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like Faraday (https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) or httparty (https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to achieve what you want. There is also a library built in ruby language `net/http` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html